# Fonts rendering differently in graphics magick

Tags: perl, fonts, truetype, graphicsmagick, perlmagick

I am using graphics magick with PerlMagick interface to create images. There are currently 2 systems which are generating the images.

System 1 is using the graphics magick version: 1.3.29
System 2 is using the graphics magick version: 1.3.18

I checked the freetype version on both the system using `freetype-config --version` command and below are the results.

system 1: 16.0.10
system 2: 9.22.3

After generating the gif image, fonts rendered on both the images are slightly different. 
I want to know whether the system 1(updated one) is rendering the font properly or system 2.

How can I validate these font renderings? I want to know which system is having the correct rendering.

Below is the sample images generated using both systems.

System1:
[image]

System2:
[image]

Comment: Please show the commands/script you used to display the images